# Performance difference when put WHERE before or after JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

In `Oracle`, say if there is join between several large table, what is the performance difference between:

```
PLAN A:
SELECT A.a, B.b, C.c
FROM A join B on a.id = b.a
       join C on b.id = c.b
WHERE A.ax = '...' and B.bx = '...' and C.cx = '....';

PLAN B:
SELECT TA.a, TB.b, TC.c
FROM (
         SELECT A.a, A.id
         FROM A
         WHERE A.ax = '...'
     ) as TA
     join
     (
         SELECT B.b, B.a, B.id
         FROM B
         WHERE B.bx = '...'
     ) as TB on TA.id = TB.a
     join
     (
         SELECT C.c, C.b, 
         FROM C
         WHERE C.cx = '...'
     ) as TC on TB.id = TC.b;
```

`PLAN A` put condition after all table join together but `PLAN B` first generate each table's subset then join them together, can PLAN B perform better than PLAN A?

Comment: CAN it?  possibly.  WILL it?  It all depends on how the server compiles and optimizes it, and what indexes are available.  It's very likely that the plan for each will be identical.

Comment: Have you compared both plans A+B ? If no, then do it, you will get an answer to your question.

Comment: Another consideration: Which looks easier to read and maintain to you?

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between the *queries* A and B, or about execution plans that looks similar to A and B?

Comment: I wonder who it was who came in and down-voted all the answers here without any reasoning of why the down vote was necessary. It seems like a very lazy and/or timid way to disagree.

Comment: @lrb Don't know who gave the downvotes. I really appreciate everyone's input. I am upvoting every answers now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your queries depend on several factors like what is indexed and what is not, index strategy, server load, data caching, the way you've written query etc. I assume the columns in `where` clause are indexed while answering -

I ran both type of queries and found a fairly similar result. (This could probably be because of how my tables and columns are setup).

Explain plan for **Plan A**

```
SELECT STATEMENT  FIRST_ROWS
Cost: 9  Bytes: 446  Cardinality: 14
```

Explain plan for **Plan B**

```
SELECT STATEMENT  FIRST_ROWS
Cost: 12  Bytes: 448  Cardinality: 14
```

Now you see both took same amount of time **but Ideally Plan A is what is considered under best practice** (speaking from experience, I've seen `Plan A` queries being used almost everywhere while `Plan B` not so much)

Different queries work differently under different circumstances [and Oracle (or any SQL engine) smartly picks algorithm that would work best for you.]

EDIT - I checked with larger dataset now

**Plan A** and **Plan B** both are same

```
SELECT STATEMENT  FIRST_ROWS
    Cost: 35,413  Bytes: 1,888,512  Cardinality: 59,016
```

Answer (score 0):

Both queries will yield the almost identical query plans.

**Plan A** will spend more time performing Index Seeks(if using proper indexes) while spending less time performing  table scans.

**Plan B** will spend more time performing Table Scans while less time performing Index Seeks (if using proper indexes).

**Plan A** is much more robust and compact.

There is not a straight forward answer and what I stated above is a cursory glance type of answer. The best way to determine the difference in your environment would be to test the outcome. The actual result is influenced on how tables are designed, how large the tables are, prior query executions, what has been cached, and a handful of other facets that are not brief enough to mention. The optimizer is usually pretty good at choosing the best plan.

Comment: Thanks. That example in the question gave an ideal situation, that the join is based on pk and foreign key. In certain scenario (bad design) what is the difference if the join is not non indexed, non-pk columns, will performance between A & B any different?

Comment: The actual plans will remain very similar or exact when no indexes are applied. The actual results will again vary and in this case both will suffer from improper indexing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, plan depends on table's statistic, [see dbms_stat](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_stats.htm). Right statistic ensure right query execution. For example DBMS_STATS.gather_schema_stats('SCOTT'); store statistic by schema [see example](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/cost-based-optimizer-and-database-statistics)

In the same time, there some options to improve plan:

1. do not use JOIN syntax, just "old" style "where". It force sql
   analyzer filter each table and then join. Hint /*+ leading() */
   ensure tables will processed in right order:

   ```
   SELECT /*+ leading(a b c) */ A.a, B.b, C.c
     FROM A, B, C 
    WHERE A.ax = '...' 
      and a.id = b.a 
      and B.bx = '...'
      and b.id = c.b 
      and c.cx = '....';
   ```
2. put filtering condition on each table just after "on" condition:

   ```
   SELECT A.a, B.b, C.c
     FROM A join B on a.id = b.a and B.bx = '...' 
          join C on b.id = c.b and C.cx = '....'
    WHERE A.ax = '...';
   ```
3. If your tables really huge and you want to filter it, cache result
   and then join, you can use hint /*+ no_merge() */:

   ```
   SELECT /*+ no_merge(TA) no_merge(TB) no_merge(TC) */ TA.a, TB.b, TC.c
     FROM (
     SELECT A.a, A.id
       FROM A
      WHERE A.ax = '...'
   ) as TA
   join
   (
    SELECT B.b, B.a, B.id
    FROM B
    WHERE B.bx = '...'
   ) as TB on TA.id = TB.a
   join
   (
    SELECT C.c, C.b, 
    FROM C
    WHERE C.cx = '...'
   ) as TC on TB.id = TC.b;
   ```

   but is better to join 2 small tables, hash result, and then join third table:

   ```
   SELECT /*+ no_merge(AB) */ AB.a, AB.b, TC.c
     FROM (
     SELECT /*+ use_hash(a b) */ A.a, A.id a_id, B.b, B.a b_a, B.id b_id
       FROM A, B
      WHERE A.ax = '...'
        AND a.id = b.a
        AND B.bx = '...'
    ) as AB,
    (
    SELECT C.c, C.b, 
      FROM C
     WHERE C.cx = '...'
    ) as TC 
    WHERE AB.b_id = TC.b;
   ```

Comment: I heard that it's better to use the new style of JOIN not the old style, it would be better if you mentioned just a little and in summary "why you prefered the old style of join".

Comment: JOIN syntax is just convenient way to write difficult condition (especially OUTER JOIN), it is "syntax sugar", but it can lead to totally different execution plan (different from old style where). So, one of options for performance tuning is rewrite query using old style. Of course it should be done only after all performance preconditions are: right statistic, indexes, pk etc.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to bring the execution plan of both above queries here and discuss on it but [Pirate X](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38109595/3208640) explained it well so I'll not mention that and I'm totally agree with him but for me I experienced sometimes bringing the where clause in the join condition had better performance (in case of time) I mean maybe writing Plan A as following may be better, it has no cost you can test it:

```
SELECT A.a, B.b, C.c
FROM A join B on a.id = b.a and A.ax = '...'
       join C on b.id = c.b and B.bx = '...' and C.cx = '....';
```

in this way at least you have no where clause syntactically.